# installed AMD catalyst driver and am stuck with 800 x 600 resolution and no unity sidebar

Tags: unity, ati, compiz, fglrx

First off, Compix kept crashing on me. I uninstalled fglrx and installed the AMD catalyst driver. When I restarted my computer my resolution stays at 800 x 600 and I can't see any sidebar icons so does that mean Unity has crashed?

Every time I update something this seems to happen to me. Can you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with every AMD driver BUT the stock one.
You can revert back to the stock drivers by opening the terminal and them settings. 
Follow the instructions below:

1. Ctrl+Alt+T (all at the came time!)
2. Type in "gnome-control-center" missing " and hit Enter.
3. In System Settings go to:
4. Software Sources
5. Additional Drivers
6. Select Open Source Driver (should be top one, Open Source is recommended as Ubuntu devs can improve it and I've found AMD drivers to crash Unity & screen resolution) & Apply Changes!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and see if it works.